# Rails Error: ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied @ sys_fail2) in dev environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running JetBrains RubyMine with rails 4.2.4, ruby 2.1.7, and am creating an application as part of a training project. I am trying to include SASS and am experimenting with certain stylesheets. I added SASS gems and import verbiage per SASS-rails documentation, and my application started throwing this (trace):

```
Errno::EACCES in Sessions#new
Showing H:/Development/RubyMine/DiceRollerWeb/app/views/sessions/new.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Permission denied @ sys_fail2 - (H:/Development/RubyMine/DiceRollerWeb/tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/v3.0/dWWzdOdzonUK3KUkyL3m5nbzYnP4jQTIQVpW3bCJg3k.cache.55176684.7688.886554, H:/Development/RubyMine/DiceRollerWeb/tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/v3.0/dWWzdOdzonUK3KUkyL3m5nbzYnP4jQTIQVpW3bCJg3k.cache)
Rails.root: H:/Development/RubyMine/DiceRollerWeb

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:525:in `rename'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:525:in `block in mv'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1579:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1595:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1577:in `fu_each_src_dest'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:514:in `mv'
sprockets (3.4.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:277:in `atomic_write'
sprockets (3.4.0) lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:108:in `set'
sprockets (3.4.0) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:210:in `set'
sprockets (3.4.0) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:136:in `set'
sprockets (3.4.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:128:in `cache_set'
sass-rails (5.0.4) lib/sass/rails/cache_store.rb:13:in `_store'
And so on...
```

I have confirmed permissions for "Everyone" to full control on the tmp directory in my project. I did a rake tmp:cache:clear several times, without success. I've tried blowing away the directory entirely without success. This isn't a Unix environment, so running chmod and adjusting group:user rwx permissions is out of the question. Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 10):

Found a different solution:

In test/test_helper.rb, commented out the following line:

```
# parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)
```

no parallell testing, no problem

Comment: This worked for me too, do you  know why ? (A bit late to the party)

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why that happens . .

Comment: Hmm, since we do not know further implications of commenting this out, I just added a -1 on each value, so :number_of_processors -1 and :threads -1. Seems less dangerous to me =d

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem.

Permissions were due to the project files living on a server share. Once I moved project files to an available spot (permissions-wise) on local C:, my issues cleared up right away.

Will consider a Linux VM option for dev.