# Permission denied on formerly working test when adding a new test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

I do the tutorial of Michael Hartl on Ruby on Rails. (Chapter 3.3.2)

Two test for testing the home page and the help page were already generated by rails.

I add the following to my code and get an error like expected.

```
test "should get about" do
  get static_pages_about_url
  assert_response :success
end
```

The Next step is adding this line to the routes file.

```
get 'static_pages/about'
```

But then I get an error which mentions the get home test, which was working before.

```
Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
ActionView::Template::Error: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (C:/Users/NCH-Lap10/Desktop/rubyprojects/sample_app/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v4.0.0/UJ/UJUHpaWHxh-dka7CVvsgGqvURvaOqYonjpkAmKgWoGM.cache.14900.18496.82620, C:/Users/NCH-Lap10/Desktop/rubyprojects/sample_app/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v4.0.0/UJ/UJUHpaWHxh-dka7CVvsgGqvURvaOqYonjpkAmKgWoGM.cache)
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Should I provide more information?

EDIT:
I run the test ten times, and all was working for three times! Seven times I got error messages.

Comment: This seems to happen on Windows in some cases judging by a google search on the error. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491772/rails-error-actionviewtemplateerror-permission-denied-sys-fail2-in-dev

Comment: @Eyeslandic You helped me. I have to comment out the parallelize. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails Error: ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied @ sys\_fail2) in dev environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491772/rails-error-actionviewtemplateerror-permission-denied-sys-fail2-in-dev)